# What are some good quantum computing simulator and visualiser?

Tags: simulation

I am looking for some good software to simulate quantum computing, visually if possible.

I know about quirk (http://algassert.com/quirk)

and IBM Q Experience (https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net)

I just saw this question ( [Does conditional gate collapse controller's superposition?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/does-conditional-gate-collapse-controllers-superposition) ) and the asker uses something that looks really neat : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIari.png

Does someone knows what this is?
And does someone knos other good software like these?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you searching a simulator, a visualiser, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will tell you what my software Qubiter ([GitHub page](https://github.com/artiste-qb-net/qubiter)) does. Others like IBM (QISKit [GitHub page](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit.org), [website](https://qiskit.org/) and [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/)), Google (Cirq [GitHub page](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq) and [documentation](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), Rigetti (PyQuil [GitHub page](https://github.com/rigetticomputing/pyQuil) and [documentation](https://pyquil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) and Microsoft (Q# [GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum) and [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/?view=qsharp-preview)) can describe what their own software does to help visualize the circuit.

Qubiter automatically creates 2 files for the quantum circuit, a Qubiter qasm file and an ASCII picture file. This makes debugging easier (Qubiter can also draw fancy LaTex picture of circuit but that is slower so only optional) The ascii file and qasm file correspond line by line, so line 5 in each gives 2 representations, ascii and qasm, of the same gate. Note that it is common to draw pictures of quantum circuits with time pointing from left to right, but Qubiter draws them with time pointing downwards.

For example, for Teleportation, this is gif of the Qubiter qasm file:

[image]

and this is a gif of the Qubiter ascii file:

[image]

The PRINT ALL statements print to screen the state vector of the qc at the time at which they appear.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the projects you mentioned in your question, the following projects come to my mind:

The Toronto-based quantum computing startup Xanadu has recently released a great [visual & interactive quantum simulator](https://strawberryfields.ai/) on the web.

And there is [QTop](https://github.com/jacobmarks/QTop) which is a great tool for the simulation and visualization of topological quantum computers.